# JDK as an archive for Windows

Tags: windows, java, jdk

My company makes use of the latest version of Oracle JRE (1.8.0u66), though I use the JDK instead of only the JRE. The client I'm dispatched to requires the latest version of Oracle JDK 6 (1.6.0u45) given they bought explicit long term support from Oracle.

Having both installed causes conflict and neither my company apps or my customer all runs correctly. If I use either one of them only, there are no issues in the respective applications.

I believe that in the past it was possible to download unzippable versions of any JDK for Windows. Now I see they all come bundled in an executable.

Given that, I know that having the latest version installed and the JDK 6 simply unzipped will work properly since nothing will be messed up in registry or stuff like that, which is currently causing the trouble. I know because I have to manually setup some important environment variables and I know how to play with those to have the client application running on my PC.

So my question is the following: is it possible to somehow retrieve an archive-only version of the JDK 6 I require for Windows? If yes, where or how?

Comment: The archive-only Windows versions started in 7. If you run any JDK.exe installer and set the third item (Public JRE) to red-X "not available" it won't install the "system" JRE which is the one that messes with the registry and does autoupdate and such. The "embedded" JRE in JDKLOC/jre can be used manually. (Personally I also exclude "JavaDB" on versions that have it.) Alternatively, IIRC the 6 license allowed you to just copy all JRE files anywhere as long as you don't replace then-Sun code with your own (i.e. you don't change "official trademarked Java" to "sort of mostly Java").

Comment: This is nice to know. I'll try this and if it works you might consider make this an answer!

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I'll write an answer with your solution and accept it. If you ever want to, please make your answer and I'll switch to yours as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [dave_thompson_085](https://superuser.com/users/333316/dave-thompson-085) explained, I have to deselect the "Public JRE" from the installation package, as showed in the image below below.

[image: Install JDK without JRE registering everywhere]